# Still confused about SQLite vs. MySQL

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am new to developing Android apps and I am deciding on whether to use SQLite or MySQL for my app.

I am still confused about what SQLite is and how it works. Please excuse my noob questions.

As far as I understand it, SQLite is local storage and serverless. My app will require user account registrations, so I'm not sure if that's possible with SQLite. I mean, how do you store user account information locally using SQLite? Say I have 3 users signing up, does each user only store THEIR username and password on their phone? So each user sees a different value for "username" and "password" in their local database? Since there is no centralized database, does that mean I as the developer do not have access to any of the users' information since all the information is stored locally on the users' phones as opposed to on a server? Why is SQLite even useful then?

Comment: SQL is a language defined by an ANSI standard and implemented in a bunch of dialects mostly in relational database systems.  SQLite is one of the databases that support a dialect of SQL.

Comment: Sorry! I meant MySQL the DBMS not SQL oops

Comment: They are two different databases with different strengths and weaknesses.  If you want a recommendation, then post a question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Read the documentation: [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Answer (score 5):

> Why is SQLite even useful then?

Computers use local files all of the time.

For example, you presumably used a Web browser to visit this site and ask your question. That program stores lots of things locally: cookies, cached data, browsing history, etc. Many other programs on your computer store files locally.

Files have their data organized in some sort of structure. XML, JSON, CSV, Markdown (i.e., the wikitext language used for Stack Overflow questions and answers), and countless others are file formats. Programmers generally use libraries that help work with those files, to read and/or write XML, JSON, CSV, Markdown, etc.

SQLite is such a library, for working with relational data (tables of rows and columns) held in a SQLite database file.

In fact, if you happen to be using Firefox as your Web browser, it uses (or used to use, anyway) SQLite for various bits of information. [Many other programs](http://sqlite.org/famous.html) also use SQLite; it may be the world's most popular embedded database.

Mobile devices, like their full-fledged computer brethren, use local files all of the time. Looking at the third-party apps on my personal Android phone, I would expect that at least half of them use SQLite.

In particular, please note that the Internet is not ubiquitous. While you may live in an area, and have adequate finances, where you feel comfortable that you have Internet access 100% of the time, not everybody is in your situation. Some people have intermittent Internet access, in which case having some data stored locally will be important.

> Since there is no centralized database, does that mean I as the developer do not have access to any of the users' information since all the information is stored locally on the users' phones as opposed to on a server?

You have no direct access to that data. However, you are welcome to:

- Read data from a Web service and use that to populate the database
- Send data from your database to a Web service as part of a periodic synchronization
- Use a database solely as a local cache (for offline use), while your "system of record" is a Web service
- Etc.

> My app will require user account registrations

It is unclear exactly what you mean by this. If you mean that you require users to sign up to use your app, as you signed up for Stack Overflow, that usually implies a central database on a server. That does not preclude your use of local files for some data, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is going to dictate which database you would use. SQLite is used as a on-device data store while MySQL would be used in conjunction with some sort of web API that has been built for you Android application.

If your Android application needs to authenticate users between devices and maybe a web based app, then MySQL with a web server is what you are looking for.

If your Android application just has user roles that are local to the device and application, then SQLite will serve you just fine.